# Netty: Can I give static Idle state handler in pipeline and channel future listener

Tags: netty

In channel Initialiser ,

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(channelGroup);
        ch.pipeline().addLast(DECODER, new MessageDecoder())
                .addLast(ENCODER, newMessageEncoder())
                .addLast(idleExecutor, "idleHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 6*60))
                .addLast(pipelineExecutor, "handler", handler);
    }
```

In the above piece of code when channel initialises can I use a static object of IdleStateHandler instead of using a new instance for every channel. Is it thread safe ?

Also,

When I write something to a channel.
I add a idle read handler to it , so that if I don't get a response withing sometime , I close the channel.

```
     ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
      pipeline.addAfter(ChannelInitializer.idleExecutor, 
"idleHandler", "idleReadHandler",new IdleStateHandler(60, 0, 0));
```

Can I use static idleReadHandler in above piece of code ?

I am using Netty-4.1.0

It was marked sharable in jboss docs until netty 3.x
https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html
But don't see in 4.x docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In netty, the rule that determines if a handler can be used thread safe between multiple channels is the [@Shareable](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.Sharable.html) annotation. Since `IdleStateHandler` is not annotated with the annotation, it means it cannot be safely used.

Comment: It was but it is not in 4.x docs
https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html. So it is  deliberate or just missed by chance ?

Comment: It can not be shared so you will need to create a new instance as Ferrybig said.